# Can't install OrientDB server

Tags: server, installation, orientdb

I'm trying to install orientdb server on my Mac (High Sierra, Version 10.13.3) after downloading Java ( Version 8 Update 191) but I'm getting "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" error.  Can you help?

Doing  ./server.sh or ./console.sh returns:

> removing old pid file
>   /Users/rony/Downloads/orientdb-3.0.9/bin/orient.pid Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   com/orientechnologies/orient/server/OServerMain : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 52.0  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

Comment: just tested a fresh download, no problem at all. Can you check your java version? Are you sure it is pointing to a java8 installation?

Comment: Hi I'm sure, Preferences shows that I have the 1.8 version while java -version shows the 1.6. This duplication appears as recurrent issue forllowing java installation as I saw it in many Stack questions. One solution, which worked for me was to install java JRE as well. Not sure why but it worked. Problem solved but thanks for looking into it.

Comment: AFAIU you're on MacOS, I suggest to use jenv (brew install jenv) to handle different jvms http://www.jenv.be/